# weird iText output with <table> & border-collapse:collapse

Tags: html, css, pdf, itext

I have the following basic table:

```css
 .tabella-test{
 border-collapse: collapse;
    }
 
    .tabella-test td, .tabella-test th{
 
 border: 1px solid black;
    }
```

```html
    <TABLE class="tabella-test">     
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th colspan="1" rowspan="2">Tree</th>
    <th colspan="1" rowspan="2">Short Description</th>
    <th colspan="2">Alberto - Group 12/2009</th>
    <th colspan="2">Andrea - Group 12/2010</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <th colspan="1" rowspan="1">Value (x1)</th>
    <th colspan="1" rowspan="1">%</th>
    <th colspan="1" rowspan="1">Value (x1)</th>
    <th colspan="1" rowspan="1">%</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>  
  <tr>
        <td>ciao</td>
  <td>test</td>
  <td>-165.889.226</td>
  <td>-29,6</td>
  <td>310.819.176</td>
  <td>150,6</td>
  </tr>  
  </tbody>
    </TABLE>
```

I'd like to put black overlapping borders around every td and th cell. I tried with the above CSS,
but in the pdf generated by iText the output is messed up, only some borders overlap. Any hint?

Comment: Are you using XmlWorker to generate this output?

Comment: yes, I switched to XmlWorker as soon as I noticed that HtmlWorker is deprecated